# How to replace expired secret key without restarting BOT

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

### Background

We have an Azure BOT which uses the graph API to do Teams call handling.
It is based on the original Microsoft BOT Call Handling Sample.

The App secret is included in the json configuration file, and is not actually used by the BOT code itself.  I therefore assume that the BOT framework is reading and using the secret at initialisation time.

Because of the nature of the BOT (handling many telephone calls concurrently) there is never a good time to restart it

### The Problem

When the secret key is due to expire, we would like to be able to change the key programmatically, so that we do not need to stop the BOT running.

Is there an API available which allows the secret key to be replaced at runtime?

If it is not possible, what alternatives exist?

Comment: Yes, you could use the Azure Key Vault to store the secret and that is pulled at runtime. All you would need to do then is update the Key Vault entry in the future.